# Trying to run WebLogic samples in VMWare Lab Manager

Tags: vmware, weblogic11g

I'm trying to do the following:
Installing a Oracle WebLogic 11g Server with the examples in a VMWare Lab Manager (virutal machine Windows XP SP3).

The problem is the following: 
According to the installation instruction everything is quite easy and should work out of the box. The installation does not show any errors.

Normally (i tried on a real machine first) it is only needed to got to

> Start - Oracle WebLogic - WebLogic Server 11GR1 - Examples - Start Medical Records Server (Spring Edition)
>   and everything should work fine (a webpage should open).

The problem is, that no Medical webpage shows up.

Digging a little bit deeper:
Start Medical Records Server is only a batch script. On the real machine (same OS) a derby server is started, on VM not.
The batch script on both machines are equal, but both call a setDomainEnv.cmd which containt on the real machine

> set DERBY_FLAG=true

and on VM

> set DERBY_FLAG=false

Changing the parameter from false to true does start up derby, but the webpage does not open.

The only info message looking liek an error shown on startup is

> Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Cl
>   ass 3,OU=T-Systems Trust Center,O=T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH,C=DE". The loading of the trusted certificate list raise a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.>

but the machine finally goes to

> Server started in RUNNING mode

Is there something else need to fire up the sample pages?

Comment: Does the admin console work at http://server:7001/console? or whichever URL ?

Answer (score 0):

the admin console starts up at localhost:7011\console , but not the samples